# Is it possible in Lua to override a function from a library?

Tags: function, lua, overriding, local

I'm trying to do a local override of a function so that I can discard the first value returned, and only one value (normally returned as its second value) will be returned by the function.

```
local r.functionName()
    discardVar,keepVar = r.functionName()
    return keepVar
end
```

However, when I run this script, I see an error:

`'(' expected near '.'`

I'm not sure how to make this work. I've only ever written functions without a "." in the function name. I'm not sure if its the right term for it, but I guess that, in this case, "r" would be the library (or maybe 'environment'?) containing the function that I want to locally override.

Basically, the desired outcome would be the function only returns one value instead of two; only the value normally returned as its *second* return value.

The closest I've gotten to succeeding with this is a legitimate stack overflow, so this seems like the right place to ask about it. :)

```
r.functionName()
    discardVar,keepVar = r.functionName()
    return keepVar
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do...

```
> -- I need to construct r with an example function
> r = {}
> r.functionName = string.gsub
> -- You start here ;-)
> replaced = r
> r = {}
> -- Fill r with replaced key/value pairs one by one
> -- So new references will be created
> -- Means: Changing r not changing replaced ( r ~= replaced )
> for k, v in pairs(replaced) do r[k] = v end
> -- Now replace r.functionName() with a function that calls replaced.functionName()
> r.functionName = function(...)
>> local f, s = replaced.functionName(...)
>> return(s) -- Syntax makes sure that only s will be returned
>> end
> r.functionName(_VERSION, '.', '')
7
> #{r.functionName(_VERSION, '.', '')} -- Number of return values
1
> -- r can than be replaced again (restored/cleanup)
> r = replaced -- Descruct of above r.functionName
> replaced = nil -- Destruct of replaced
> collectgarbage('collect') -- Freeing unused memory
```

Comment: Could you possibly edit this answer to reference the particular library.name of the function I'm trying to override within a specific script (r.functionName)? I'm having trouble understanding how this would result in a call to r.functionName yielding a different result.

Comment: Done - Hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: Indeed it does! Thank you for the detailed comments and clarification!

Answer (score 5):

First save the function

```
local f = r.functionName
```

Then replace it with your implemention

```
r.functionName = function()
    local discardVar,keepVar = f()
    return keepVar
end
```

Note that this will replace the function in the library `r` too, so if the library itself internally depends on this function name, it can fail.

Comment: will the change to the library be permanent, or might it only be in effect until the current script is finished, or until the application is relaunched? For context, I'm using a DAW application (REAPER) for audio, which implements Lua as an API for "ReaScript" to make changes to the project and various other settings/parameters. More info: https://code.google.com/archive/p/realua/ and https://www.reaper.fm/sdk/reascript/reascript.php

Comment: Not permanent, it only changes the function in current scope.